# Is it possible to run a large number of docker containers?

Tags: docker, algorithm

A small introduction to history. I am building a small service (website) where the user is provided with all sorts of tools that work according to the parameters specified by the user himself. In my implementation, it turns out that the tools are one big script that runs in the docker. It turns out that my service should launch a new docker container for each user.

I was thinking about using "aws fargate" or "gcloud run", or any other resource that makes it possible to run a docker container.

But I'm interested. What if there are 1000 or 10000 users, each one will have its own docker container, is that good? Do the services (aws, gcloud) have any restrictions, or is it a bad implementation?

Comment: Dynamically launching containers can be troublesome, especially at scale – you need to keep track of everything you've launched and clean it up when it's done.  Also consider, in plain Docker, that being able to launch a container gives you unrestricted root-level access over the entire host.  I'd very seriously look into other implementation paths.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for your answer. Perhaps you have experience, or could you advise how other services/companies cope with a similar task, perhaps in which direction to look?

Comment: You can run an AWS instance per customer.  If usage is light, you can multiplex - many AWS instances each of which is running some number of containers.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/post/how-we-clone-a-running-vm-in-2-seconds is highly relevant to this exact use case.

Answer (score 2):

Based upon my understanding you have suggested that you instantiate a Docker container for each of your users, I think there are a couple of issues with this:

1. Depending on how many users you have you get into the realms of too many containers. (each container will consume resources, not just Memory and CPU but also TCP/IP pool exhaustion.)
2. Isolation -> Read [containers are not VMs](https://www.docker.com/blog/containers-are-not-vms/)